# Activity to Fragment with existing content

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I wrote a simple App with Two Activities, The First is my `MainActivity` and the Second is my `MapsActivity`.
The Code works perfectly in my `MainActivity`, when i press a Button i will get redirected to my `MapsActivity` with fixed `LatLng` and my actual Location.

Now i came to the conclusion that i want to implent a `TabLayout` (in Total 3 Tabs).
The First Tab should contain the Buttons and the functionality of my `MainActivity`
As already all Buttons and all the code is in my `MainActivity` i need to transfer it to the First Fragment.
This didnt work out, since im using alot of `findViewById` and the Fragment does not like that.

**`MainActivity`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button button;
private Button btnred;
private Button btnaura;
private double v1;
private double v12;
private double vend;
private double v1end;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.fvroth);
    button =  findViewById(R.id.btnroth);
    btnred= findViewById(R.id.btnRednitz);
    btnaura = findViewById(R.id.btnaurach);
    btnaura.setOnClickListener(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnred.setOnClickListener(this);
    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new weiherPageAdapter(this));

    TabLayout tabLayout =findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator= new TabLayoutMediator(
            tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: {
                    tab.setText("Fliesgewässer");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24);
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    tab.setText("Weiher");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_24);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    tab.setText("Schon-maß und Zeiten");
                    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_announcement_24);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    );
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();




}
public void openMapsActivity(){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
    LatLng position= new LatLng(v1,v12);
    intent.putExtra("Pos",position);
    LatLng positionende = new LatLng(vend, v1end);
    intent.putExtra("PosEnde",positionende);
    startActivity(intent);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnroth:
             v1= 49.21344;
            v12= 11.171002;
            vend= 49.211946;
            v1end= 11.158726;
            openMapsActivity();
            break;
        case R.id.btnRednitz:
            v1=  49.250451;
            v12= 11.084395;
            vend= 49.269385;
            v1end= 11.076057;
            openMapsActivity();
            break;
        case R.id.btnaurach:
            v1= 49.244672;
            v12= 11.043886;
            vend=49.254027;
            v1end= 11.080881;
            openMapsActivity();
            break;
                            }
}
```

**`MapActivity`**

```
  public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;


    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

        // Construct a GeoDataClient


    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
                   {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currentLocation.getLatitude()+""+currentLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        LatLng position = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Pos");
        LatLng positionende= getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("PosEnde");
        LatLng aktpos = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("Anfang"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(positionende).title("Ende"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(aktpos).title("ich").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position,15),1000,null);
    }

}
```

For Better understanding here a Picture of the App.
[image]

Comment: Fragment will also allow you usage of findViewById in onCreateView() method. val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)\n
// get the ids\n
return view

Comment: Could it work when I just transfer my buttons,(or create new ones) in the fragment and set the click listener to the buttons in the fragment? And let the rest of the code in the main activity?

Comment: basically, your view should be present at one place, and your logic should be in another place. If you want to update some view, then try to pass your data from business logic to your view, instead of passing your views to business logic.